# Android. Как запрашивать координаты в отдельном потоке?

Tags: android, gps, геолокация

Есть класс-сервис FusedLocationService, он реагирует на изменение координат и запускает onLocationChanged в активити. Теперь мне нужно брать данные в фоне в отдельном потоке, чтоб данные приходили без перебоев, когда приложение закрыто. Как это делается? в основном все примеры были написаны когда еще не было FusedLocation API, FusedLocation используют для получения координат в фоне в отдельном не убиваемом потоке? Если да, то можно пример?

Comment: Генадий Здраствуйте .Вы нашли ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Нашел, просто надо не убиваемый сервис сделать и в нем запрашивать координаты у FusedLocation API

Comment: можешь ссылку кинть ?я щас по ней тужусь никак немогу ...

Comment: твя реализация мне помоглаб

Comment: Нет не могу я это уже ниче не помню, просто найди пример реализаци получения координат в отдельном потоке, и  привяжи его к неубиваемому сервису фореграунд.

Comment: хорошо спасибо:)

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;import android.util.Log;import android.view.View;import android.widget.Button;import android.widget.TextView;import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
Button btnFusedLocation;
TextView tvLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mCurrentLocation;
String mLastUpdateTime;

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");
    //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    createLocationRequest();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);

    btnFusedLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    btnFusedLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            updateUI();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    startLocationUpdates();
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    updateUI();
}

private void updateUI() {
    Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
    if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
        String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
        String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        tvLocation.setText("At Time: " + mLastUpdateTime + "\n" +
                "Latitude: " + lat + "\n" +
                "Longitude: " + lng + "\n" +
                "Accuracy: " + mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy() + "\n" +
                "Provider: " + mCurrentLocation.getProvider());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "location is null ...............");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
    }
}}
```

Android Layout File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LocationActivity"
android:background="#ffffa6c7">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/locationTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Location"
    android:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ffff1a7c"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="134dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Пример смотрите здесь
https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: а как же мой вопрос "FusedLocation используют для получения координат в фоне в отдельном не убиваемом потоке?"

Comment: Создаем новый поток,  а лучше используй сервис

Comment: опять не правильно, зачем вы людей путаете если сами в теме не разбираетесь?